# What are those things in Han's Pocket?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens

Han's fancy new jacket has plenty of pockets.

What are these things?

[image]

Comment: Corellian Pez dispensers.

Comment: Energy Gels to stave off bonking?

Comment: I assumed it was some sort of e-cigarette.

Comment: Trader Saun Dann seems to have them in [his jacket](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/File:Artandpeter.jpg) as well

Comment: This fan-pic identifies them as "[pilot flares](http://i.imgur.com/jvu5eXU.jpg)"

Comment: I always thought it was some sort of small cigar case, like will smith has in independence day.

Comment: Sausages.  He watches *It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia*.

Comment: I always wondered what glitterstim doobies looked like in-universe....

Comment: Deathsticks, maybe

Comment: Video of the guy making them: http://punishedprops.com/2016/04/06/han-solo-pocket-tubes/ and Reddit discussion: https://www.reddit.com/r/electronic_cigarette/comments/3xlcsc/what_are_those_supposed_to_be_in_han_solos_jacket/

Comment: Maybe he’s just pleased to see Rey?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They're detonators.

Page 46 of the [visual dictionary](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Awakens-Visual-Dictionary/dp/0241198917) shows this picture:

[image: photo of the page, with detonators on the left]

While nothing states that what he has in his pocket are the detonators, the tip of what's poking out of his pocket closely resembles the bottom of the detonator (seen on the left hand of the page).

Further evidence that they're not fuel cells for the blaster are on the same page,  where the fuel cell labelled is a cuboid.

Further,  the only similar item I can see on 'modern' resistance pilots are signal flares, seen on Snap Wexley's leg.

[image: visual dictionary page showing Snap Wexley's signal flares]

On the older uniforms,  the arm patch does indeed hold data cylinders (and safe passage documents for downed pilots) :

[image: Luke showing off his data cylinders from a previous dictionary]

I presume pilots no longer need safe passage documents nor data cylinders. They also probably don't need detonators,  where a guy like Han would.

Comment: Damn. +1 for making me feel dumb. He's **shown dealing with detonators in the novelization, duh!**. Well, and for awsome answer :)

Comment: I'm not entirely convinced. I've been playing with [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/PLXFI.png) for about ten minutes now and try as I might, I can't find a way to size the detonators so that they fit into his pocket as shown, even if you chop off the bottoms.

Comment: @Richard,  that's a good counterpoint. It's possible that it's a prop issue,  but I haven't got anything better.

Comment: Hmm. The authorised jacket maker calls them "ammunition holders"; http://www.matchlesslondon.com/en/starwars/

Comment: @Valorum:   Why do the two images of detonators have to be the same model of detonator?   You don't need to get those detonators to fit in those holes.    Detonators come in all sizes.   And maybe it was cold outside.

Answer (score 0):

I think detonators is probable answer, but after Han gives chewbacca a detonator he still has all three objects in his front pouch thing and he seemed to just have it in his hand

Comment: This would probably be better as a comment.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why they are likely to be detonators?

Comment: Do we actually see what he hands him?

Comment: Flagged as NaA since it rather looks like a comment on the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I ready on another site that these are "code cylinders". So, a smuggler like Han might have use for them to get authorization to dock at certain ports? Not sure how accurate that is.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in a link to this "other site"? Sourced answers tend to be preferred over unsourced ones :-)

Comment: Hi nick welcome to the site. If youd like please take a [tour] of the site, and heres a helpful link for [ask] -ing future questions.